# React responsive image without srcset?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to confirm whether or not React is able to serve responsive images without needing srcset tag in html.

Using state with the window width, I can set conditional renderings of images. Using chrome and checking the network flow, it seems the desired images are being served without having to serve all images.

```
import React from "react"
import images from "../assets/images"


class App extends React.Component{
    state = {
        width: 0
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize)
        this.setState({
            width: window.innerWidth
        })
        console.log(this.state.width)
    }
    handleResize = () =>{
        this.setState({
            width: window.innerWidth
        })
        console.log(this.state.width)
    }
    render(){
        const image = this.state.width > 1000 && this.state.width !== 0 ? images.HD : images.LD
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={image} alt="hd/ld"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Is this a valid way to serve specific images with different resolutions?

Comment: Using client hints (DPR, Width, and Viewport-Width) but it has very less support

Comment: https://github.com/stereobooster/react-ideal-image/blob/master/introduction.md

Comment: Valid? Sure, it will definitely work. But why would you want to complicate your component(s) by managing the logic manually when you could use a srcset and let the browser deal with it? Is there a reason you're trying to avoid srcset?

Comment: @Kirbee Say I have an array of images which I want to be responsive. How would I apply an array of images using srcset? I feel like allowing the component to handle the logic is more appropriate for such things.

Comment: @EduardoUeda Why would an array be different? You can loop over the array (or better yet, `Array.map`) and create an `<img>` tag for each with a srcset attribute. What are you worried about with the array?

Comment: @Kirbee Oh right, that works. Thanks.